# Accounting for repeated measurements vs cross section with averages

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, cross-section

If I had repeated measures of the units in my sample, is it always preferable to analyse as is and account for these with a method such as GEE or a multi-level model - because of the gain in information -, or are there times when it is better to average within unit and analyse the data cross sectionally?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to say "always" in response to any statistics question.

Why might you want to use averages instead? I think all the following would have to apply:

- You aren't interested in change over time.
- You aren't interested in variance within subjects
- Your variables are suitable for taking means. This isn't always the case.

and maybe some other conditions that I am not thinking of.

Given all that, the analysis on the averages will be simpler to specify and probably easier to interpret, and will be familiar to a wider audience.